# Присвоить переменной значение ячейки

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, ado

Делаю запрос в БД Users, запрос для авторизации. Заодно нужно переменной 'office' присвоить значение из столбца logo данной строки.

Клиент вводит логин и пароль. Идет сравнение с базой и нужно еще вытащить значение из ячейки для дальнейшего сравнения (смотрите код).

Не могу сообразить, как составить запрос.

```
private void InputButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string office="";
    SqlCommand cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Users where login = '" + LoginBox.Text + "'and password= '" + PasswordBox.Text + "' and office=logo";
    if (office=="P1")
    {
 
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ресурсы нужно освобождать. Для этого заключаем их в блоки `using`.

SQL-запросы нельзя составлять с помощью конкатенации строк. Причина: [Внедрение SQL-кода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Взамен используем параметры.

Так как вам в данном конкретном случае нужно вернуть всего одно значение, то в запросе пишем `select logo ...`. И используем метод `ExecuteScalar`.

Если запрос не нашёл пользователя с совпадающим логином и паролем, то вернётся значение `null`. Можете использовать проверку `if (office == null) ...`.

```
string office;

string sql = "select logo from Users where login = @login and password = @password";

using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();

    using (var sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandText = sql;

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("login", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LoginBox.Text;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PasswordBox.Text;

        office = (string)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Здесь `_connectionString` - строка соединения. Она является полем класса.

---

А теперь самое главное. Не храните в БД пароли! В базе данных должны храниться *хеши* паролей, и желательно с солью. Вот замечательная статья по теме: [Adding Salt to Hashing: A Better Way to Store Passwords](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/). Большая, но зато подробно объясняющая, что к чему.

И почему в таблице колонка называется logo, а в коде вы используете office?

Comment: string sql = "select logo from Users where login = @login and password = @password";  Мне очень помог вот этот запрос. Дальше пару своих строк и заработало. Спасибо

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Я не знал что ресурсы заняты всегда.

Comment: про хеш паролей. Мне надо сначала пользовательский пароль хешировать? потом занести хеш в базу? Затем как юзер вводит пароль нужно опять хешировать и сравнить с хешем который сохранен в базе? А когда его нужно расхешировать?

Comment: @ЕвгенийН - вообще, вопрос про хеширование (и соление) паролей вполне можно задать отдельной темой. Только так вы можете получить подробное объяснение (но и минусов можно нахватать).

Comment: @ЕвгенийН - в целом вы понимаете правильно. За одним исключением: `когда его расхешировать?` - никогда. Это невозможно. В этом и суть хеширования! Даже если базу данных украдут, пароли невозможно будет узнать из неё.

Comment: @ЕвгенийН - _как вернуть два значения_ - задайте новый вопрос отдельной темой. Наш сайт не форум, это сайт типа "Вопрос-Ответ". Задаёте конкретный вопрос - получаете точный ответ.